# Write to a file whose name is a matched string in a sed script

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have meeting protocols with tasks to be done, each one starting with keyword `TODO` and ending with `D/nameOfAssignee`, like this:

```
Meeting 2017/03/22
some stuff
TODO task for philipp D/philipp

some more stuff

TODO task for jane D/jane
TODO task for joe D/joe

some other stuff TODO Another
task for Philipp
D/philipp

still
more
stuff

TODO Yet another
task for jane   D/jane
```

Now I want to get a file `philipp.txt`:

```
task for philipp
Another task for Philipp
```

and a file `jane.txt`:

```
task for jane
Yet another task for jane
```

and a file `joe.txt`:

```
task for joe
```

I do this with `sed`:

```
sed -n '/TODO/!d
  :l
  /D\//bw
  N
  bl
  :w
  s/.*TODO *//
  s/\n/ /g
  s_ *D/philipp__w philipp.txt
  s_ *D/joe__w joe.txt
  s_ *D/jane__w jane.txt
' tasks.txt
```

This works, but for each possible assignee, I need an identical line in the script, which starts to get annoying. In the documentation I don't find a way to use a regex-matched substring in the filename like:

`s_ *D/\(.*\)__w \1.txt`  (This doesn't work! Everything is written to a file named `\1`!)

Is there another possibility to first generate the script which I can use in a second run with automatic generation of those lines for each assignee?

Or is `sed` simply the wrong tool and should I do stuff like this in `python`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do what you want but it only works with GNU sed.

```
sed -rn '/TODO/!d 
  :l
  /D\//bw
  N
  bl
  :w
  s/.*TODO *//
  s/\n/ /g
  s_(.*) *D/(.*)_echo \1 >> \2.txt_e
' tasks.txt
```

The secret is the special `e` switch in the substitution command which executes the content of the pattern space as shell code. Also note the use of `-r` to be able to use grouping.

Credits go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679479/how-can-write-the-multiple-files-with-sed-from-pattern-matched

Comment: Brilliant! Not fully portable, but I use gnu `sed` anyhow. Thank you, this was the one I was hoping for! And even shorter than `awk` (or `perl`) and without piping.

Comment: Yep, 'e' is one funny sed command. But this is so twisted it actually makes me wonder if I'll be able to understand my own answer next week... If you need to use variables in your script, sed is definitely not the right tool.

Comment: Yes, it would be more straight forward if `w` switch would directly accept back references like I suggested. Anyhow, I don't find your solution hard to understand. But maybe others did find the whole script confusing, so it didn't even get a single vote for thoughtful question ... (-;

Comment: Ups. You're right. Here's mine, because your question was actually well-written and you did your homework before asking.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
awk '{F=0;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if($(i-1)~/TODO/){F=1}if(F){printf("%s ",$i)}}printf("\n")}' RS="D/" tasks.txt | awk '{print > $NF".txt"}'
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't resemble the desired output as I described it: The output files only contain the first task of each assignee, don't have the stuff removed like my `sed` does and a crazy file `Yet.txt` is produced.

Comment: modified the answer.. can you try this..

Comment: Works (except for dividing my taks between `philipp.txt` and `Philipp.txt`, but we can avoid uppercase spelling in the list). Thank you. Anyhow, I'll leave the question open some more time, hoping for an answer on how to achieve this in `sed`.

Comment: You can save 3 more characters from that command line by removing spaces around `|`, and by changing `> $NF` to `>$NF`.  Otherwise, it's about as unreadable as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should indeed write a script. It would at least be easier to maintain and document than a long sequence of sed transformations (but that's my point of view, you may disagree).

Here is a Perl proposal:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
#

sub printTodo {
    my ($todo,$person) = @_;
    my $file;
    open($file, ">>$person.txt");
    print $file "$todo\n";
    close($file);
}

if (/TODO (.*)D\/(\S*)/) {
    printTodo($1,$2);
} elsif (/TODO (.*)/) {
    $found = "$1 ";
} elsif (/(.*)D\/(\S*)/) {
    $found .= $1;
    printTodo($found,$2);
    $found = undef;
} elsif ($found) {
    chomp $_;
    $found .= "$_ ";
}
```

Assuming you save this script as `script.pl` and your meeting report as `meeting`, you would call it this way: `./script.pl < meeting`.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl

`Slurp` tasks.txt and look at strings starting with `TODO` and look for the nearest `D/` and we may even jump across newlines in order the need arises to do so. `m//s`.

A novel feature is that if we were to run this thing a second time, then the generated `*.txt` files aren't appended to, rather they start afresh in each spin. Hence by construct, they will never face the runaway-size syndrome.

```
perl -MFatal=open -l -0777ne '
  do{open my $fh, $h{$2}++ ? ">>" : ">", "$2.txt"; print $fh $1 =~ y/\n/ /rs}
     while m|\bTODO\s*(.+?)\s*D/(\S+)|sg' tasks.txt
```

## sed + ed

As is ususal in such cases, we dynamically construct an `ed` code to get the output. What the novel feature in this scenario is that the data file upon which the `ed` code would operate is itself dynamically generated from the same input.

So it's like data+code is found inside the data.txt which is separated and then brought together as inputs of `ed` to generate the output from `ed`.

```
sed -n '
   /TODO/!d
   :l
   /D\//bw
   N
   bl
   :w
   s/.*TODO *//
   s/\n/ /g
  #<----------------------- ORIG --------------------->#

   H;s| *D/.*||w /tmp/data.txt
   g;s/.*\n//;x;s/\(.*\)\n.*/\1/;x

   G;s/\n/&&/
   h
   / *D\/\(.*\)\n\(\(.*\n\)\{0,\}\)\1\n/!{
   s/.*[^ ] *D\/\(.*\n\)\n/\1/
   x
   s/\n\n.*//
   s|\(.*[^ ]\) *D/|/\1/w |;s|$|.txt|p;$!d;s/.*/q/p;q
   }

   g
   s/\n\n.*//
   s|\(.*[^ ]\) *D/|/\1/W |;s|$|.txt|p;$!d;s/.*/q/p;q
' tasks.txt | ed -s - /tmp/data.txt
```

## Caveat:

Make sure that no person name to whom task is assigned is named "tasks".